# Why do we always import .csv files to R instead of .xls files?

Tags: r, excel, statistics, analysis

Why do we always import .csv files to R instead of .xls files? Is there any advantage?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. You import the file you have. Are you asking for pros/cons of saving/sharing data in CSV vs XLS?

Comment: I import .xls or .xlsx all the time. That really depends on what you have.

Comment: xsl (the old one) is a binary data format, CSV is just data.

Comment: I agree with @Gregor - you import what you have. Main reason why I never work with excel files is that you can't *operate*, *view*  them on the remote server where only cli is available.

Comment: Not to mention that XLS/XLSX capable (and often do) encode *much* more information than is generally needed for analysis. The XLS format is designed to encode a table-based visual display of data with all sorts of bells and whistles. Generally when you want to do analysis you want clean, rectangular data, which is readably encoded in a csv/tsv without the option for complications.

Comment: `.csv` is typically a much more predictable file than `.xlsx` and `.xls`. With Excel files you often have extra headers and formatting that require clean up before analysis. Also, using a function like `data.table::fread()` we can read very large data sets quickly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Historically, it was hard to import xls files in R
2. We need to load a library to load xls
3. xls is a proprietary format and you need to have MS Excel to be sure in your data content

Now i often use xlsx files to save/load some data structures. Unfortunately, i've got some bugs with export the data with large "user input" strings.